# Exit activity diagram at any point

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

We're currently designing an application with an exit button, meaning the user can exit the application at any time. Now, we're not sure how to write this down.

Right now, we're thinking about doing it like shown in the picture below, because this is the only way we know how to do this. However, we feel like there must be an easier way. Also: if we do this for our whole application (which is quite big), we'd get a whole ton of decision and end nodes...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model looks ok. Instead of having multiple `Final Flow`s you could lead all flows to a single one (just as an option).

Without knowing the exact requirements, here is another way:

[image]

The exit button is treated as exception. This could as well be written as

[image]